# 3 lists keep becoming copies of each other even when only one list is changed

Tags: python, list, game-engine

Context: I'm a low intermediate level programmer trying to make a game with my own code in order to improve my ability. I know pygame etc... exists but I wanted to try and make my own engine. I'm currently trying to create a display system. My thought process was to create a 2D list: SURFACE where `SURFACE[y][x]` is a 'pixel' at coordinates x,y on the python console. This worked great. But I wanted more, and thought: Why don't I create 3 levels of surface, BACKSURFACE, MIDSURFACE, and FRONTSURFACE. My idea was that I could create a single flattened image by combining whatever is rendered through BACKSURFACE, MIDSURFACE, and FRONTSURFACE. This way I could do things like, create an options menu that overlays on top of the game without clearing the entire display.

Now comes my Issue. I created a function `addToSurface()` that takes a surface, the x, y positions of where to render the image/text, and a list that contains the render item.

```
def addToSurface(surface, x_pos, y_pos, renderItem):
    global SCREENWIDTH, DISPLAYHEIGHT
    returnSurface = []
    returnSurface = surface.copy()       # Make a copy of the surface list
    itemHeight = len(renderItem)
    itemWidth = len(renderItem[0])

    if itemHeight <= DISPLAYHEIGHT and itemWidth <= SCREENWIDTH:
        render_y = 0
        for y in range(y_pos, itemHeight+y_pos):
            render_x = 0
            for x in range(x_pos, itemWidth+x_pos):
                if renderItem[render_y][render_x] == " ":      # Because the 'image' files are ASCII, I turn every
                                                               # space in the image into a [None] pixel. The 
                                                               # original surface lists are initialised where
                                                               # every pixel is [None]
                    returnSurface[y][x] = [None]
                else:
                    returnSurface[y][x] = renderItem[render_y][render_x]  # If a pixel in the image isn't empty
                                                                          # the equivalent pixel coordinate in the
                                                                          # surface becomes the pixel.
                render_x += 1
            render_y += 1

    return returnSurface       # A new version of the surface is returned.
```

For example, if I run `BACKSURFACE = addToSurface(BACKSURFACE, 0, 3, logoImage)` where `logoImage` is a 2D list containing an ASCII image of my games logo, what I expect is for BACKSURFACE to now contain the logo at starting at BACKSURFACE[3][0] (coordinates 0, 3). Like I mentioned above, this works great. But for some reason, after creating my MIDSURFACE, and FRONTSURFACE lists, everytime I run `addToSurface()` all three lists are changed.

So now, when I run `BACKSURFACE = (addToSurface(BACKSURFACE, 0, 3, logoImage))`, not only does BACKSURFACE come with the logo rendered, so do MIDSURFACE and FRONTSURFACE, even though they haven't been referenced in the program at all after initialisation. For reference, here are my other functions in the program so far:

```
def __init__(height, width):
    global SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT, TITLE, BACKSURFACE    
    global MIDSURFACE, FRONTSURFACE, DISPLAYHEIGHT
    SCREENWIDTH = width
    SCREENHEIGHT = height
    DISPLAYHEIGHT = height - 11                                 #The above 3 lines are just to set display size.

    for i in range(DISPLAYHEIGHT):                              # This loop creates the 2D lists for all surfaces
        temp = []                                               # where each pixel has a default value of [None]
        BACKSURFACE.append(temp)
        MIDSURFACE.append(temp)
        FRONTSURFACE.append(temp)
        for j in range(width):
            temp.append([None])


def openImage(imageName, centre=False):
    temp = []

    dir = os.path.join(imageDirectory,imageName)
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        
        return null

    elif not centre:

        with open(os.path.join(imageDirectory, imageName), "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                temp.append([char for char in line.rstrip("\n")])
            f.close()

    elif centre:
        
        with open(os.path.join(imageDirectory, imageName), "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                centredLine = tech.centre(line.rstrip("\n"))
                temp.append([char for char in centredLine])
            f.close()

    return temp
```

Like I mentioned above, I would describe myself as just past begginer level programming and this is definitely the most complex thing I've ever attempted. Even so, I have a feeling it's going to be something really simple. If you could point out where the error is and why it's an issue I'd be more than happy. If anyone could suggest a fix I'd appreciate it as well.

Comment: You're explicitly filling all three with references to the same list `temp` at each index. It's unclear why you expected that to give them separate lists.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks so much for pointing that out. I completely glossed over that, after changing the way the SURFACES are initialised it works perfectly as desired. Much appreciated!